# c# uwp Layout Cycle log

Tags: c#, logging, uwp, unhandled-exception

In C# UWP is there a way of logging this error's stack trace?

Because, the app crashes, and there is no any information that can help determine why that happened.

I am using HockeyApp for tracking and logging errors.

This is how output looks like:

```
UWP_Destiny!<BaseAddress>+0x751e6c
UWP_Destiny!<BaseAddress>+0x76f936
UWP_Destiny!<BaseAddress>+0x76f864
Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object sender, ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e)
```

Layout Cycle is more then 80% of all errors in my app, and I cannot reproduce it on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

> In C# UWP is there a way of logging this error's stack trace?

From the HockeyApp [official site](https://hockeyapp.net/features/crashreports/),

> We process and symbolicate all crash reports on our servers. That means you get meaningful stack traces with class names, methods, and accurate line numbers.

HockeyApp should provide meaningful stack traces. But the report you uploaded looks no meaningful. Please ensure that you uploaded symbol (*.pdb) files to HockeyApp in order to symbolicate crashes for your UWP application. Details for how to do please reference [How to upload symbols for UWP application](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application).